# Is it possible to use facebook social plunging comment box to comment on my profile picture

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone tell me Is it possible to use facebook social plugin comment box to comment on a picture in my profile?
This is the code for facebook social plugin comment box

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="MY_URL" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

I **tried this by replaying MY_UR with url of a facebook image** in my profile(which is taken from garph api with a given image id).

```
<?php
$det = $facebook->api('/IMAGE_ID');
$image_url = $det['link'];
?>

<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

**But it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?**
Note : I have the **publish stream permission**.

Answer (score -1):

You need to point the `fb:comments` `href` to the page that's hosting the comments plugin. This is where users will click when they see stories in their newsfeed after one of their friends has commented on your photo.

Comment: Can you please explain it with more details. Using this way, can I comment on a facebook picture?(a picture which is in my profile).I'm developing this for a facebook application(Not for a website).When user accessed the app, it display a image of my profile with the comment box + all posted comments of that image.I know how to display the image inside my canvas page.Now I need to add the comment box?

Comment: The comments plugin has to be hosted on a page somewhere. You need to make a unique url for each photo. For example http://www.example.com/photo/1 which would display a photo and allow people to comment on that photo, and then a different url like /photo/2 for people to comment on that url.